# Spark (sSala) merge variable number of DataFrames generated from a map function

Tags: scala, join, merge, apache-spark-sql, mapping

I have two `DataFrame` (`dfMain` and `df`) both of 3 columns of the `String` type (`"col1", "col2", "col3"`). I need to map a function to each row (`r`) of `df` and based on some criteria, those elements which are in `dfMain` and fulfill the criteria be selected, and then sampled.

The final result should be returned as an integrated one `DataFrame` (i.e. `Dataset[Row]`). My buggy incomplete (scala) solution is below. Since the criteria in the `map` can become more complicated, I would appreciate a solution which is more generic and allows to merge the result of the `map` (i.e. the generated `DataFrames`) to be merged.

```
case class record(col1: String, col2:String, col3:String)

def myFun(df: DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
  df.as[record].map{
    r => dfMain.filter($"col1" !== r.col1 &&
                       $"col2" === r.col2 && 
                       $"col3" === r.col3 )
               .sample(false,0.2)
  }
}
```

Comment: are you looking to filter in the rows from dfMain whose col1 is not equal to df col1 and rest two columns are equal?

Comment: Hi Ramesh and thanks a lot  for your answer.  Principally, in the map I have some criteria to select elements from `dfMain`. For each row of `df`, I need to select some elements of `dfMain` using those criteria (I wrote one of these cases in my question). As criteria in the `map` can get more complicated, I would appreciate a solution which allows the results of the `map` on each row of `df` (i.e. the generated DataFrames by the maps) be merged together. Do you have a solution for merging the generated DataFrames?

Comment: didn't my solution below help you ? You can't use dataframes inside map of another dataframe. the only solution is to join them. and you can use union for merging two dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have two `dataframes` as

```
dfMain 
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|a1  |b1  |c1  |
|a   |b2  |c3  |
|a   |b3  |c4  |
+----+----+----+
```

and

```
df
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|a   |b1  |c1  |
|a   |b2  |c2  |
|a   |b3  |c3  |
+----+----+----+
```

Now looking at your code in question, you are trying to `filter in` the `rows` from `dfMain` whose `col1` is not equal to `df col1` and rest two columns are equal i.e. `.filter($"col1" !== r.col1 && $"col2" === r.col2 && $"col3" === r.col3)`. If thats the case then you should go with `join`

```
dfMain.as("main").join(df.as("table"), $"main.col1" =!= $"table.col1" && $"main.col2" === $"table.col2" && $"main.col3" === $"table.col3", "inner")
```

which should give you

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|a1  |b1  |c1  |a   |b1  |c1  |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Now if you want only the `columns` of `dfMain`, you should do

```
dfMain.as("main").join(df.as("table"), $"main.col1" =!= $"table.col1" && $"main.col2" === $"table.col2" && $"main.col3" === $"table.col3", "inner")
    .select($"main.col1", $"main.col2",$"main.col3")
```

which should be

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|a1  |b1  |c1  |
+----+----+----+
```

And if you want only the `columns` of `df`, you should do

```
dfMain.as("main").join(df.as("table"), $"main.col1" =!= $"table.col1" && $"main.col2" === $"table.col2" && $"main.col3" === $"table.col3", "inner")
    .select($"table.col1", $"table.col2",$"table.col3")
```

which should generate dataframe as

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|a   |b1  |c1  |
+----+----+----+
```

Or you can have mixture output of both `dataframe` `joined`.